# "Error: no matching function for call to" C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment where we have to create a header and source file to be used in a pre-existing main source file. I have some functions that are supposed to be called, but the program says that the functions don't match.

My main problem is that in the main code, it says that there are "no matching function for call to" both Student::addGrade and Student::computeGPA. I was able to get this program to compile earlier by removing the "const Student& aStudent); from the declarations of computeGPA and addGrade (in my .h file), and have the variables in the actual definition of the functions (the ones in student.cpp) be simply "qp" or "credits" instead of "aStudent.qp" or "aStudent.credits". My program was able to compile, but it gave me a clearly wrong output (a number of around 40 digits or so, as opposed to a name and a number with two decimal places). I do not understand why my program says that the function doesn't match to the call, and I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

The preexisting code that calls my header and source files is

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include "gradeValue.h"

using namespace std;


void gpaCalc (istream& input, ostream& output)
{
string name;
getline (input, name);
int credits;
double qp;
input >> credits >> qp;
Student student(name, credits, qp);
string grade;
input >> grade >> credits;
while (grade != "0" && credits != 0)
{
   student.addGrade (grade, credits);
   input >> grade >> credits;
}
double gpa = student.computeGPA();
output << student.name << ' '
  << fixed << setprecision(2) << gpa << endl;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{


if (argc > 1)
{
  ifstream inputFile (argv[1]);
  gpaCalc (inputFile, cout);
}
else
gpaCalc (cin, cout);
return 0;
}
```

Here's the files I've written myself, student.h and student.cpp

**student.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
#define STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
struct Student
{
Student(std::string name, int credits, double qp);
std::string name;
int credits;
double qp;
double computeGPA (const Student& aStudent);
void addGrade(const Student& aStudent, std::string grade, int credits);
};

#endif // STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
```

**student.cpp**

```
#include "student.h"
using namespace std;
struct GradeValue {
string  grade;
double value;
};
const GradeValue gradeValues[] = {
    {"A", 4.0},
    {"A-", 3.7},
    {"B+", 3.3},
    {"B",  3.0},
    {"B-", 2.7},
    {"C+", 2.3},
    {"C",  2.0},
    {"C-", 1.7},
    {"D+", 1.3},
    {"D",  1.0},
    {"F",  0.0}
};

 double findGradeValue (const GradeValue table[], int tableSize, string grade)
{
for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i)
if (table[i].grade == grade)
  return table[i].value;
return table[tableSize-1].value;
}

void Student::addGrade(Student& aStudent, string grade, int credits)
{
aStudent.credits += credits;
double v = findGradeValue(gradeValues, 11, grade);
aStudent.qp += credits * v;
}
double Student::computeGPA(const Student& aStudent)
{
if (aStudent.credits > 0)
    return aStudent.qp / aStudent.credits;
else
    return 0.0;
}

Student::Student(std::string name, int credits, double qp) {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you call `computeGPA`, you don't pass any parameters:

```
double gpa = student.computeGPA();
```

...but in the header, where you've declared `Student::computeGPA()`, you specify it as taking a parameter:

```
double computeGPA (const Student& aStudent);
```

...therefore, the call and the function don't match, and the compiler tells you it can't find a function that matches a call passing no parameters.

Likewise, where you call `addGrade` you pass two parameters, but the declaration says it expects three.

At a guess, you probably want to eliminate the `Student &` parameters--member functions will normally act on the object on which you invoked them.

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions for your Student class' functions are strange, and this strangeness I believe caused you to implement them incorrectly as well as call them incorrectly.  When you have a member function, you don't need to pass it itself, so you can omit that part.  These lines in `student.h`:

```
double computeGPA (const Student& aStudent);
void addGrade(const Student& aStudent, std::string grade, int credits);
```

Should likely be:

```
double computeGPA ();
void addGrade(std::string grade, int credits);
```

Then, in the implementation of them, you should replace `aStudent.` with `this->`.  You have the following (note that addGrade is missing `const` on its `Student` parameter, but it doesn't matter cause we're gonna delete it):

```
void Student::addGrade(Student& aStudent, string grade, int credits) {
  aStudent.credits += credits;
  double v = findGradeValue(gradeValues, 11, grade);
  aStudent.qp += credits * v;
}
double Student::computeGPA(const Student& student) {
  if (credits > 0)
      return aStudent.qp / aStudent.credits;
  else
      return 0.0;
}
```

consider changing them to:

```
void Student::addGrade(string grade, int credits) {
  this->credits += credits;
  double v = findGradeValue(gradeValues, 11, grade);
  this->qp += credits * v;
}
double Student::computeGPA() {
  if (credits > 0)
      return this->qp / this->credits;
  else
      return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: This was able to get it to compile, but it now does the same thing as my code when I had already removed the "Student& aStudent" and such; the output of the program spits out a massive number that is nowhere near what it should actually output (i.e., instead of getting "John Doe, 3.45", I get "17791354043261738 and about three lines of 0s before a .00") I thought that the error was that not having some of the variables be stemming from my Student class would make this number, but I guess not.

Comment: You aren't initializing any of the variables in the student class.  In the constructor of Student you need to initialize name, credits and qp, otherwise you'll get garbage values like that.